# If statement not being executed when it is expected to work

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following three tables - `users_thoughts`, `users` and `post_favourites`. I have a feature in my social networking site which allows users to favourite a post (posts are stored in `user_thoughts` and when a post is favourited i.e. when `favourite_post.php` is called, it will store the favourites in `post_favourites` table).

If the logged in user has **NOT** favourited a post, it will show the `Glyphicon heart-empty`. But if the user **HAS** favourited a post, it will show `Glyphicon-heart`.

Lets assume I have the following rows in my tables:

`users` table:

```
id: 1
first_name: conor

id: 2
first_name: Alice

id: 3
first_name: Anderson
```

`user_thoughts` table:

```
id: 100
message: This is a post by Alice.
added_by: Alice

id: 101
message: This is a post by Anderson
added_by: Anderson
```

`post_favourites` table:

```
id: 1
user_id: 1 (This is the id of the user who has favourited the post, see users table)
thought_id: 101
```

Assume I am logged in as `Conor`. As you can see `Conor` has favourited `Anderson`'s post, so `Glyphicon-heart` should appear, as logged in user has already favourited Anderson's post. But `Glyphicon-heart-empty` is appearing, even though my database says conor has favourited anderson's post.

**Here are my queries**:

**Note**: `$username` is the session variable created for the logged in user.

```
$count = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_thoughts_from_db)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
}
    // Get all user_ids attachted to a thought ($thought_id)
    $get_user_id = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM post_favourites WHERE thought_id = '$thought_id'");
        $id_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_user_id);
        $all_user_id = $id_fetch ['user_id'];
        $post_id = $id_fetch ['thought_id'];

    // get id of users from users table
    $get__id = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
        $id_fetch2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get__id);
        $logged_in_user = $id_fetch2 ['id'];    

if ($post_id == $thought_id){
    // If the post has already been favourited by the username, then display this icon with funtionality.   
         if ($all_user_id == $logged_in_user){
                echo "$get_num_of_favs
                <a href='/inc/unfavourite_post.php?id=";?><?php echo $thought_id;?><?php echo "'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart' aria-hidden='true' style='padding-right: 5px;'></span> 
                    </a>";
                 }
            // if the post hasn't been favourited by the username, display this icon.
            else {
                echo "$get_num_of_favs
                <a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id=";?><?php echo $thought_id;?><?php echo "'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' aria-hidden='true' style='padding-right: 5px;'></span> 
                    </a>";
            }
         }
```

I need it so already favourited posts by the user who is logged in are dislayed with `heart` icon i.e. the if statement is executed. But at the moment, Anderson's post of `This is a post by Anderson`- which is favourited by Conor, is showing with `heart-empty` - meaning the else statement is being executed and I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without your data, but I would put my money on it being that more than one user has favorited this post. Then, the first result returned by

```
$get_user_id = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM post_favourites WHERE thought_id = '$thought_id'");
```

will not have the user_id of the current logged in user. You should add the $logged_in_user to the WHERE clause:

```
$get_user_id = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM post_favourites WHERE thought_id = '$thought_id' AND user_id = '$logged_in_user'");
```

(Don't forget to escape any data before querying! )

Comment: Hi Tim. Seems to be some progress with this change. Anderson's post is now being displayed with `heart` icon, but when I go onto Alice's `profile_page.php`, to see her posts, no icons at all are being displayed next to her posts. I would expect to see `heart-empty` next to all of Alice's post, since logged in user `Conor` has not favorited any of Alice's posts.

Comment: Has neither of you heard about joins?

Answer (score 0):

The whole complex logic in php can be substituted by using [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) in the sql query to combine data from all relevant tables:

```
select *
from user_thoughts u
left join post_favourites p on u.id=p.thought_id and u.user_id=$_SESSION['userid']
```

`$_SESSION['userid']` is the user id of the currently logged on user. Store it in session along with the user name.

When you loop through the resultset in php, if thought_id=='' (empty string), then you know that the current user did not like this post yet.